# Laravel vendor published views not being referenced

Tags: laravel-5.4

I'm using notifications to send email and want to edit the email templates. After publishing the vendor views (php artisan vendor:publish) the new directories with the views are created but they are not being referenced.

If for example if edit views/vendor/mail/html/message.blade.html and save, the changes I made are not displayed.

But if I edit the original view files in the core Illuminate/mail/resources/views/html/message.blade.html my changes are displayed.

So for some reason it still references the core view files instead of the published view files.

I have tried cache:clear and view:clear and still no luck.

Comment: Need more info. Please (1) show the method where your are rendering your view, (2) your view file, (3) dir structure.

Comment: (1) I'm using the notify method.. example $user->notify(new ToMemberWelcome($user));  (2) The views from laravel that work out of the box. My issue is that after vendor:publish they are being copied to the views/vendor/mail/html/ but not being referenced. They are still being referenced at Illuminate/mail/resources/views/html/